# Error: erlang: no bottle available! on Mac OS 10.13

Tags: macos, installation, erlang, erl

I'm facing an error while trying to install the Erlang/OTP in MacOS 10.13.6. I am trying:

```sh
brew install erlang
```

But I am getting the error: `Error: erlang: no bottle available!`.

[I have attached the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuaLq.png)

Comment: To help enrich your questions (and make it more searchable via Stack Overflow or Google), I recommend investigating the error messages, and potentially typing out the error messages in the question. The screenshot image was helpful -- I would post both.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, it says:

```
Error: erlang: no bottle available!
```

And on the [erlang package description for Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/erlang#default), it says it doesn't support your Mac Version (10.13). Note "High Sierra" isn't listed in the "Current versions" that are supported.

I recommend one of the two alternatives:

- Install [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) (langauge manager) and then [asdf-erlang](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf)
- Use homebrew to install an older version of Erlang; one that supports 10.13 (High Siera). It looks like [erlang@21](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/erlang@21) supports `high_sierra`.

Personally I recommend 'asdf' for development purposes. It does erlang and numerous other languages. Once you get it set up, it becomes very easy to adopt other environments.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Now I am facing error while building the project with ./rebar3

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511882/error-while-building-erlang-project-with-leveldb

Comment: @MohanKrishnan - if you were able to install Erlang, would you mind marking this question as being answered? ;) Thanks.