# Error while building erlang project with leveldb

Tags: macos, shell, erlang, leveldb, rebar3

I am getting the error with leveldb while running the following.

**./rebar3 shell**

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: There was another report of "expected ';' at end of declaration list for leveldb builds on Mac OS: https://github.com/google/leveldb/issues/637. Given that you're trying to install leveldb via rebar3, you might fiddle around with various package versions: eg downloading an older version of leveldb, trying to install it manually and linking to it. You might also try posting your leveldb issue in the erlang project in question. Chances are the installation doesn't handle for your environment.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency `{eleveldb, "2.2.20"}` compiled fine for me when I executed `$ rebar3 shell` on Mac OSX 10.13.6.

Your error message says that you should upgrade rebar3.  Did you do that?

Finally, don't ever post screen shots of your output--instead post the output itself.  Presumably, you know how to copy and paste text.